# Sharepoint 2013 fail product configuration wizard at step 8

Tags: 2013, configuration-wizard

I have been struggling with this issue for a couple days. From what I've search until now there is no problems with my 15 hive `admin.sitemap` or `layouts.sitemap`. None of them have comments or anything than can cause failure to read the XML. In the log I only have following trace:

```
09/07/2015 11:26:52  15  ERR  An exception of type System.NullReferenceException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAspSiteMapFile.MergeAspSiteMapFiles(XmlDocument xmldocSiteMap, String strSrcFilePath, String strMergeFilePattern)
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAspSiteMapFile.Copy(String strSrcDir, String strSrcDirPrevious, String strSrcLeaf, String strDestDir, Boolean bMergeMaps, Boolean bBackupExistingFile)
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.CopyAppDomainDirectories(DirectoryInfo vrPath, OverwriteSetting overwrite)
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService.ApplyApplicationContentToLocalServer()
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ApplicationContentTask.Run()
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
09/07/2015 11:26:52  15  INF  Entering function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
09/07/2015 11:26:52  15  INF  Entering function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
09/07/2015 11:26:52  15  INF  Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
09/07/2015 11:26:52  15  INF  Resource id to be retrieved is ExceptionInfo for language English (United States)
09/07/2015 11:26:52  15  INF  Resource retrieved id ExceptionInfo is An exception of type {0} was thrown.  Additional exception information: {1}
09/07/2015 11:26:52  15  INF  Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
09/07/2015 11:26:52  15  INF  Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
09/07/2015 11:26:52  15  INF  Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
09/07/2015 11:26:52  15  INF  Entering function get CommandCollection.this[string key]
```

I'm wondering if anyone have this issue and how to solve this. I'm running the following infrastructure:

- Front-end server (public facing)
- App Server (sharepoint 2013 with last 11 August CU installed on both servers)
- SQL Server

All servers are Windows Server 2012 with R2.
No language packs installed.

This environment is still on stage. Its suppose to be production environment and all 3 servers were prepared to bring up a migration from a public site currently running on sharepoint 2010 with couple customizations, so yes I have deployed some custom features. At this point I retracted all my custom solutions. I also have servers running with Reporting Service, installed on both front end machines. All my accounts should be correct, since I have farm account, admin account and specific accounts for services, so I don't believe issue is about permissions.

Please any help will be much appreciated :)

Thanks
Bruno

Comment: See if this helps: https://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2012/07/16/exception-in-mergeaspsitemapfiles-for-sharepoint-2010-products-configuration-wizard-psconfig/. Also, googling this will give you lots of results too.